# Does Tora get more blades?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

I've just unlocked the third blade slot for my other characters but Tora is currently a bit under-powered considering he only has one possible element to add to any combo and one set of arts..

Does he ever get another blade, or the ability to change Poppi's role/element/whatever in battle to make him as versatile as the other characters?

I've tried looking stuff up online but I'm not far into the game yet really and don't want to spoil anything..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid spoilers, I'll just leave it at this: Tora does get more Blades.

> To be more specific, he gets two Blades as part of the story and through a sidequest. One Fire and one Ice although you can change those elements with Poppiswap.

Comment: Great, I'll look forward to that then. Right now he's just a damage sponge and not much else. It would be nice if he could contribute more to combos

Comment: Is it unavoidable? Basically can you miss out on getting Tora more blades?

Comment: @user1821961 I think I've just reached the point in the story where you get the second one so as that's part of the main quest line it should be unmissable. I'm not sure if there are any missable sidequests in this game or not, I haven't noticed any yet anyway.

Comment: The second is unmissable, the third is part of a side quest.